# the attributes 'j_username' and 'j_password' were shown as a plain text under Form Data in the request header

Tags: spring, spring-security, filter

I am facing one of a security issue that Chrome dev tools were showing these attributes 'j_username' and 'j_password' as a plain text under Form Data in the request header.

It is an old application, in which we are using acegi-security 0.8.2 with Spring framework.

Workaround in our project: 1. in web.xml, we have mentioned the filter ChannelProcessingFilter as a separate filter,

```
<filter>
<filter-name>Acegi Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
<filter-class>net.sf.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy</filter-class>
 <init-param>
 <param-name>targetClass</param-name>
 <param-value>net.sf.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy
 </param-value>
 </init-param>
 </filter>

  <filter>
  <filter-name>Acegi Channel Processing Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>net.sf.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy</filter-class>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>targetClass</param-name>
  <param-value>
     net.sf.acegisecurity.securechannel.ChannelProcessingFilter</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>
```

2..In applicationContext.xml, we have defined the ChannelProcessingFilter,

```
<bean id="channelProcessingFilter" class="net.sf.acegisecurity.securechannel.ChannelProcessingFilter">
   <property name="channelDecisionManager"><ref bean="channelDecisionManager"/></property>
   <property name="filterInvocationDefinitionSource">
     <value>
       CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
          PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT    
       /login.htm*=REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL
       /j_acegi_security_check*=REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL
       /admin/**=REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL
       /**=REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL
     </value>
   </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="channelDecisionManager" class="net.sf.acegisecurity.securechannel.ChannelDecisionManagerImpl">
   <property name="channelProcessors">
     <list>
       <ref bean="secureChannelProcessor"/>
       <ref bean="insecureChannelProcessor"/>
     </list>
   </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="secureChannelProcessor" class="net.sf.acegisecurity.securechannel.SecureChannelProcessor"/>
 <bean id="insecureChannelProcessor" class="net.sf.acegisecurity.securechannel.InsecureChannelProcessor"/>
```

3.To only deliver the login page over HTTPS, we have enabled the SSL/TSL support by generating keystore and enabled the Connector port="8443" in conf/server.xml in the tomcat server
The problem here am facing is, on clicking the j_acegi_security_check request, in Chrome dev tools was showing these attributes 'j_username' and 'j_password' as a plain text under Form Data in the request header.

Am I missing anything here? Kindly help me on encrypt this password or disable this attribute as how it is implemented in the banking applications

Comment: Chrome tools shows the form data before it is encrypted for HTTPS.

Comment: @holmis83, but this is the same case for IE, it shows the details under Request Body and for Mozilla also, it shows the Form data under PARAM tab